# Re run a c++ program based on user input or condition

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm learning c++ and as an exercise with arrays and user input, I'm trying to write a simple poker application. 
Since I'm at the begin of this course, all I know about the c++ language is that the execution of the code is demanded to the `main()` function. I've write some lines of code that is the base of the final app, it works fine for now. I want to implement a loop to re run the app based on the user input and on a condition that for the scope of the app will be the amount of th fish variable quantity after every execution. How I can achieve this? Another question is about the use of random elements from an array. Is there any good reference where I can learn how to do this?

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name;
    int bet;

    int fish = 100;
    char seed[4][10] = {"hearts","clubs","diamonds","spades"};
    int cards[9] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    std::cout << "Welcome in PokerBash! Please enter your name:" <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;

    std::cout << "Your name is " << name <<std::endl;

    std::cout << "You have a credit of:" << fish <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please enter your bet:" <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> bet;

    std::cout << "Your cards are " << seed[2] << " " << cards[3] << " " << seed[1] << " " << cards[7] <<std::endl;

    std::cout << "Your credits after this bet:" << fish - bet <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_I want to implement a loop_" What's stopping you in doing that? If you don't know the syntax of loops in C++, consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I know about the loops with the `for` or `while`, but I don't know how to implement it to re run the program.

Comment: Why do you need to re-run the program, instead of re-running the logic of the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a loop that stops if the user wants to or `fish` is less than `0` by making a [`while`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while) loop that depends on some boolean `playing` that is initially `true`. So if one of the two events happen, set `playing` to be `false` and the loop stops:

```
int main() {
    //variables

    bool playing = true;
    while (playing) {
        int fish = 100;

        //poker game

        if (fish < 0) { //no money
            playing = false;
        }
        else {
            char input;
            std::cout << "would you like to play again? (y/n): ";

            std::cin >> input;
            if (input != 'y') {
                playing = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, this repeats until I enter something that isn't `'y'`:

```
would you like to play again? (y/n): y
would you like to play again? (y/n): y
would you like to play again? (y/n): n
```

---

to choose a random element from an array you would use the utilities from `<random>` like their [`std::mersenne_twister_engine`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine). To get a random element from an array you would basically just need create a random number and use that as the arrays index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 engine(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 8);


    int cards[9] = { 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    while (true) {
        std::cout << cards[distribution(engine)] << '\n';
    }
}
```

some important things from here:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937_64 engine(rd());
```

is done only once (never in a loop). It is for initializing your pseudo random generator `engine`.

> `std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 8);`

adds a distribution. Note that, because your `int cards[9]` has `9` elements, the range has to go from `0` to `8` as arrays start at `0`and end at their size - 1, as you might probably already know. :)

Running this you can see it randomly prints out the card numbers from `2` to `10`:

```
2
10
7
9
2
4
9
10
8
9
8
6
8
2
10
```

These are your helping points to implement further. I add some more things I noticed about your code but are not necessary to the question itself.

---

You should note that you should not `use namespace std` - you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why.

---

Also, instead of:

```
char seed[4][10] = { "hearts","clubs","diamonds","spades" };
```

use:

```
std::string seed[4] = { "hearts","clubs","diamonds","spades" };
```

To use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) include the `<string>` header.

---

you wrote `std::cin >> name;` but this doesn't work for strings with spaces, like look here:

```
Welcome in PokerBash! Please enter your name:
Stack Danny
Your name is Stack
```

To get the full name, use

```
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm trying with the `do(){ }while();` and it'a nice starting point, I will try your code to implement a more robust solution for my simple app. Since I need to show the cards of a poker game, is there a simple way also to check the user cards to output a win message ?I was thinking to use the `if()` `else` control structure to do this, but maybe it will be too complex?

Comment: if you have to check for something you will have to use `if()` statements no matter what. But if it's 20 if statements in a row you probably did something wrong. Feel free to post your code here (with a pastebin link) for me to take a look at that approach.

Comment: For now I didn't write this part of the code, I need first to do a list of the winning cards of a poker single manche. I've asked this as you had understood because I want to avoid a bigger `if()` structure, I think there is a better way to do this task. For every suggestion feel free to contact me in chat

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int bet;
    int fish = 100;

    char seed[4][10] = {"hearts", "clubs", "diamonds", "spades"};
    int cards[9] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    while (1)
    {

        std::cout << "Welcome in PokerBash! Please enter your name ( Enter q to quit ):" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;

        if(name == "q")
            exit(0);

        std::cout << "Your name is " << name << std::endl;

        std::cout << "You have a credit of:" << fish << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please enter your bet:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> bet;

        std::cout << "Your cards are " << seed[2] << " " << cards[3] << " " << seed[1] << " " << cards[7] << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Your credits after this bet:" << fish - bet << std::endl;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```